# Set Constraints on 6 buttons.

Tags: xcode, constraints, xcode8

Anyone know the correct way of adding constraints to these 6 buttons? The button sizes is not important as I want them to adjust based on the screen size. [image]

Comment: Why don't you use `UICollectionView`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is `UIStackView`. You can stack each pair of buttons horizontally, then put the 3 pairs into another vertical stackview!

Pretty good tutorial here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views